# Joomla custom user groups

Tags: joomla, usergroups

I have a Joomla website and there are two sections to the site. One section is for the public and the other is for retailers which have to be approved. What I need is to create a group of users which are the only ones who can access the retailer section of the site. These users don't get any editing/publishing/administrator roles; they're just registered users with special access. I've tried several extensions but had no luck with it. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: What version of Joomla! are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need groups: you just have to make sure to disable the "self registration" option (from admin control panel: **Global Configuration -> system -> Allow User Registration = No**)

[image: Global Configuration]

Also, you'll have to configure each article/menu to have **Access Level** "*public"/"registered*".
 [image: article/menu permissions] 
You can register new users from the admin control panel and only they will be able to view "*registered*" content.

Comment: Well the thing is that regular public users will still be able to register but I need to make it so some registered users can access certain parts of the site but others can't.

Comment: for that you have a third option (access level) called "special". But I never used it so I can't provide more details in regards.

Answer (score 0):

Read this :-
http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/1.6-2.5/Tutorial
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/9040
Search about access control list.